# JavaScript extracting data from XML (if else statement not working)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

So my problem in the code below is in the following if else if statement at the bottom:
 1. the code in both of the if statements work perfect.
 2. the issue is that when i run the code on one can be use.
    if i do 2 separate if statements only the second one works.
    if i do 1 if and one else if only the if statement works and the else if does nothing.

a little more info: what I'm trying to do is every time the function times out and loops through again it will check the if statements and if something changed to run the appropriate if clause.
PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF MORE INFO IS NEEDED.

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
var xmlHttp;

if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e)
    {
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}
else
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e)
    {
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}

if(!xmlHttp)
    alert("cant create object");
else
    return xmlHttp;


}

function process_search()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{
    search_parameter = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
    search_type = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userOptions").value);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "../pages/search_xml.php?search_parameter=" + search_parameter +      "&search_type=" + search_type, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
else
{
    setTimeout('process_search()',5000);
}
}

function handleServerResponse()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{
    if(xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        root = xmlResponse.documentElement;

        if(document.getElementsByTagName('find_users'))   // FIND USERS
        {
            first_name = root.getElementsByTagName('first');
            last_name = root.getElementsByTagName('last');

            users = document.createElement('ul');
            users.setAttribute("id", "usersFound");

            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = "";   //RESETS THE DIV BEFORE INSERTING DATA
            for(var i=0; i< first_name.length; i++)
            {
                usersList = document.createElement('li');
                t = document.createTextNode(first_name.item(i).firstChild.data + " - " + last_name.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>");
                usersList.appendChild(t);
                underInput = document.getElementById("underInput");

                underInput.appendChild(usersList);
            }
        }else if(document.getElementsByTagName('find_config_item'))   //FIND CONFIG ITEMS
        {
            item = root.getElementsByTagName('item');
            desc = root.getElementsByTagName('description');

            itemsList = document.createElement('ul');
            itemsList.setAttribute("id", "itemsFound");

            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = "";   //RESETS THE DIV BEFORE INSERTING DATA
            for(var i=0; i< item.length; i++)
            {
                itemList = document.createElement('li');     // CREATE LIST ITEM ELEMENT
                t = document.createTextNode(item.item(i).firstChild.data + " - " + desc.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>");
                itemList.appendChild(t);
                underInput = document.getElementById("underInput");

                underInput.appendChild(itemList);
            }
        }


        setTimeout('process_search()', 5000);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("something is wrong");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really rely on try/catch for this use case. You can be fairly certain the XMLHttpRequest or a Mircrosoft.XMLHTTP object will exist so you could simplify your code to the following:

```
function createXmlHttpRequestObject () {
    return window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new XDomainRequest();
}

var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
```

Let me know if you would like to see a non ternary version

Comment: thanks for  that ..worked perfect andi understand it...what about the original question regarding my problem with the if else if. if i run it, it still has the same issue]

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking sorry. Could you please clarify?